# How to change sql server connection string dynamically in service stack

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack, servicestack-bsd

I am working on Asp.Net MVC and ServiceStack. I am trying to connect to the sql server database using servicestack ormlite. like

```
 var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AppDb"].ConnectionString;
 container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(
 new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(connectionString,
                    SqlServerOrmLiteDialectProvider.Instance)
                {
                    ConnectionFilter = x => new ProfiledDbConnection(x, Profiler.Current)
                });
```

I am able to connect to database, But in my scenario i need to change the connection string dynamically.. That means i need to read the content from Request body and prepare a connection string. In servicestack we configure sql server connection string in AppHost class that means at app start. But i need to set the connection string in my controller. **I have tried like place it in session and use that session in ClassLibrary SeviceBase class**. But I am unable to use asp.Net sessions in class libraries.How to change sql server connection string dynamically in service stack. so please guide me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would change the `IDbConnectionFactory` to be reused in the scope of the request, instead of the current default, which shares it among all requests.
I have also created a static method (`GetDatabaseConnectionFactory()`) which returns the instance of `OrmLiteConnectionFactory` to the IoC container with the custom connection string.

To determine the connection string, I have used a request filter, which simply reads the parameter `connectionstring`. If it is not set it will use a default value. This value is then 
set in the `RequestContext.Items` collection, which can be accessed by the `GetDatabaseConnectionFactory()` method.

Remember exposing connection strings this way is dangerous, always check any connection string values thoroughly to ensure they don't contain malicious values. *i.e. Ensure they don't try to connect to administrative databases, or a different server, or change default setting overrides etc.*

In your AppHost:

### ServiceStack V3:

```cs
public override void Configure(Container container)
{
    container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(c => GetDatabaseConnectionFactory()).ReusedWithin(ReuseScope.Request);

    RequestFilters.Add((req,res,obj) => {
        // Default value
        var defaultConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AppDb"].ConnectionString;

        // Get the connection string from the connectionstring parameter, or use default
        var dbConnectionString = req.GetParam("connectionstring") ?? defaultConnectionString;

        // You should perform some checks here to make sure the connectionstring isn't something it shouldn't be
        // ...

        // Save the connection string to the HostContext.Instance.Items collection, so we can read it later
        HostContext.Instance.Items.Add("ConnectionString", dbConnectionString);
    });
}

public static IDbConnectionFactory GetDatabaseConnectionFactory()
{
    // Read the connection string from our HostContext Items
    var dbConnectionString = HostContext.Instance.Items["ConnectionString"];

    if(dbConnectionString == null)
        throw new Exception("Connection string has not been set");

    // Return the connection factory for the given connection string
    return new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(dbConnectionString, SqlServerOrmLiteDialectProvider.Instance) {
        ConnectionFilter = x => new ProfiledDbConnection(x, Profiler.Current)
    });
}
```

Usings:

```cs
using System;
using Funq;
using ServiceStack.ServiceInterface;
using ServiceStack.ServiceHost;
using ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints;
using ServiceStack.OrmLite;
using ServiceStack.Common;
```

### ServiceStack V4:

```cs
public override void Configure(Container container)
{
    container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(c => GetDatabaseConnectionFactory()).ReusedWithin(ReuseScope.Request);

    GlobalRequestFilters.Add((req,res,obj) => {
        // Default value
        var defaultConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AppDb"].ConnectionString;

        // Get the connection string from the connectionstring parameter, or use default
        var dbConnectionString = req.GetParam("connectionstring") ?? defaultConnectionString;

        // You should perform some checks here to make sure the connectionstring isn't something it shouldn't be
        // ...

        // Save the connection string to the RequestContext.Items collection, so we can read it later
        HostContext.RequestContext.Items.Add("ConnectionString", dbConnectionString);
    });
}

public static IDbConnectionFactory GetDatabaseConnectionFactory()
{
    // Read the connection string from our Items
    var dbConnectionString = HostContext.RequestContext.Items["ConnectionString"];

    if(dbConnectionString == null)
        throw new Exception("Connection string has not been set");

    // Return the connection factory for the given connection string
    return new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(dbConnectionString, SqlServerOrmLiteDialectProvider.Instance) {
        ConnectionFilter = x => new ProfiledDbConnection(x, Profiler.Current)
    });
}
```

Usings:

```cs
using System;
using Funq;
using ServiceStack;
using ServiceStack.Data;
using ServiceStack.OrmLite;
using ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite;
```

Comment: I am using ServiceStack version 3.9.43.0 dll, I am unable to compile above code, some types are not founding. I need to read request body i.e. InputStream of Request object.

Comment: @KarthikBammidi I wish you had mentioned that in your question somewhere, I'll try and update. What is the content-type of the data you are sending? Is it a form POST, you shouldn't need to access the InputStream directly.

Comment: An external wpf application calls my MVC application with some data like, `WebBrowser objBrowser = new WebBrowser();
objBrowser.Navigate(url, "_blank", Encoding.Default.GetBytes(queryString), "");`

Comment: The data that wpf application will send of type is pure text i.e. string content.

Comment: @KarthikBammidi So that's a [`byte[]` of post data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161355(v=vs.110).aspx). Which is formatted as a query string, which will be read and made available as a form parameter. So there shouldn't be any need to read the `InputStream` directly.

Comment: Yes exactly, but i am unable access Request form parameters or querystring value in AppHost.cs page. I am getting Request is null and then exception. I am able to read the post data in controller action method.

Comment: @KarthikBammidi OK so my method should work, except that it needs to  be made v3 compatible. Give me a few moments.

Comment: @KarthikBammidi I have added the code for v3. You will need to change `req.GetParam("connectionstring")` to have the name of the parameter you posting the connection string as. But you should be able to adapt as required.

Comment: I taught it is working. In my scenario that is while calling  from external application, when i debug my web app, at first time it calls my controller-action and i got posted data but it did not call apphost.cs method. and then immediate call has happened to my controller-action again and i got empty posted data, this time it called apphost.cs file so it takes default connectionstring. Is there any way of using sessions in AppHost.cs please guide us.