# EF with dynamic database password

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm working on C# MVC 5 app that each user must username, password, server, and database to connect.

For each user, the authentication DLL will provide a unique connection string. The password works only for one user during a section time. Each user has different permissions on tables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change sql server connection string dynamically in service stack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22712879/how-to-change-sql-server-connection-string-dynamically-in-service-stack)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is the question? If you need to change connection string do it in Context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString, then call Open. It should be work.

Comment: Each user has a unique connection string. I can't store the connection string on Web.config.

Answer (score 0):

using MVC 5 Controller with view, using EF .. ( make sure you have model and view like CRUD system) 
and if you want each user have unique connect , using guid();

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid(v=vs.110).aspx